# Reading a csv file into a dictionary

Tags: python, csv

My code looks like this:

```
from sys import argv
import csv

person = {}

file = argv[1]
sequence = (open(argv[2], 'r').read()).strip()

with open(file, 'r', newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for k, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 in reader:
        person[k] = [v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7]
```

Is there any other way to iterate through the columns to add in the dictionary more succinctly or efficiently? As in, for example, if you wouldn't know the number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to achieve this: use the first element in row as the key, and the remaining elements as the value.

```
with open(file, 'r', newline = '') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        person[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`unpacking`](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/#:%7E:text=Unpacking%20in%20Python%20refers%20to,the%20iterable%20unpacking%20operator%2C%20*%20.):

```
with open(file, 'r', newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for key, *values in reader:
        person[key] = values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the `csv` file directly into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

then put it into a dictionary

`data.to_dict()`